# Set not storing collection of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a map of a struct (nodeT) initialised which is called map_nodes, whose keys are a string name that is a city name and the values are a pair of coordinates (where the city is located).

I am trying to store a set in this struct as well, which would collect the number of outgoings "arcs" for each city.

These are my structs:

```
struct arcT {
int distance;
nodeT *start, *end;

};

struct nodeT {
string name; 
coordT coordinates;
Set<arcT*> outgoing; 
};
```

I am trying, in a larger function that reads in a data file line by line, to also add each finished arcT to the set in the node that is also that particular struct's "start" node.

However, it is not being stored properly. It adds a pointer to the set, but when I check the value of a set for a given node at the end of the program, it is empty. Here is the function that adds to the outgoing vector for a given node (in addition to some other operations for creating the arcT struct):

```
void addArc(Map<nodeT> & map_nodes, string line) {

Scanner scanner;
scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::IgnoreSpaces);
scanner.setInput(line);

string start = ""; string end = ""; int distance = 0;

while (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) {

    arcT *arc = new arcT;

    start = scanner.nextToken();
    nodeT *temp = new nodeT; 
    *temp = map_nodes.getValue(start);
    arc->start = temp;

    end = scanner.nextToken();
    nodeT *temp_next = new nodeT;
    *temp_next = map_nodes.getValue(end);
    arc->end = temp_next;

    distance = StringToInteger(scanner.nextToken());
    arc->distance = distance;

    nodeT *temp_last = new nodeT;
    *temp_last = map_nodes.getValue(start);
    temp_last->outgoing.add(arc);
    cout << "The city is: " << start << " and the size: " << temp_last->outgoing.size() << endl;
}
}
```

Function prototype is: void addNode(Map & map_nodes, string line);

Why won't these arcs be stored in the set of the corresponding start node? The size is always 0 when I try to getValue of the set for a particular node.

Comment: This is not C code, I removed the tag.

Comment: What does `map_nodes.getValue(start)` and `scanner.nextToken()` do?  Could you highlight what exactly you expect to contain values, but doesn't?

Comment: I can't see any map... Map (in general) should have to template parameters: key type and value type. It seems that `Map<nodeT>` is just a container of `nodeT`'s, but not a map. What **are** `Set` and `Map` ?

Comment: Since std::set != Set, what is Set?

Comment: temp_last->outgoing.add(arc); stores all the data you have created in a temporary object that you loose at each iteration. temp_last don't point to the object in your map. It points to a temporary object that contains a copy of the data from you map (which is not really a map). Nice memory leak at the end.

Comment: You have memory leaks and all modifications you are trying to do are made to leaked objects and lost with them. You need to improve your grasp of pointers, memory management and object ownership.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, pointers is really something I'm having  a lot of trouble with.

Comment: @Soren, those two are members of a library that have been included as header files. The scanner.nextToken() works file, it just goes through a line and picks out the next non-whitespace character. getValue is a member function of the map class, and it returns the value at a given string. I do think the problem here does have to do with pointers...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Set and Map have been defined in pre-written header files. I'm using the Stanford library and the definitions of a container seem to be working fine...

Comment: @PhilippeLignon How would I go about addressing this? Everytime I try to do a direct assignment, it gives me "cannot convert nodeT to nodeT*" in assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have three memory leaks in `addArc()`

```
void addArc(Map<nodeT> & map_nodes, string line) {
  Scanner scanner;
  scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::IgnoreSpaces);
  scanner.setInput(line);
  string start = ""; string end = ""; int distance = 0;

  while (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) {
    arcT *arc = new arcT;
    start = scanner.nextToken();
    nodeT *temp = new nodeT; 
    // MEMORY LEAK
    *temp = map_nodes.getValue(start);
    arc->start = temp;
    end = scanner.nextToken();
    nodeT *temp_next = new nodeT;
    // MEMORY LEAK
    *temp_next = map_nodes.getValue(end);
    arc->end = temp_next;
    distance = StringToInteger(scanner.nextToken());
    arc->distance = distance;

    nodeT *temp_last = new nodeT;
    // MEMORY LEAK
    *temp_last = map_nodes.getValue(start);
    temp_last->outgoing.add(arc);
    cout << "The city is: " << start << " and the size: " << temp_last->outgoing.size() << endl;
  }
}
```

I have removed these errors and cleaned up the code a little (*would appreciate if someone could verify that the reduced code is reduced correctly!*):

```
void addArc(Map<nodeT> & map_nodes, string line) {
  Scanner scanner;
  scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::IgnoreSpaces);
  scanner.setInput(line);
  while (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) {
    arcT *arc = new arcT;
    string start = scanner.nextToken();
    arc->start = &map_nodes.getValue(start);
    arc->end = &map_nodes.getValue(scanner.nextToken());
    arc->distance = StringToInteger(scanner.nextToken());
    arc->start->outgoing.add(arc);
    cout << "The city is: " << start << " and the size: " << arc->start->outgoing.size() << endl;
  }
}
```

As far as I can see this should be working though, if `Set` works as one would expect. Therefore my conclusion is that `Set` is not working as one would expect.

Also we do not see what `Map` is nor where the value for `map_nodes.getValue(start)` is originally populated. So we do not know what is being returned and what pointer you are trying to modify. Does `Map` do bounds-checking? Are you sure you are handling an object that is actually valid?

**Memory Leaks**

```
A* a = new A();
a = someOtherPtr;
```

When you used `new` then you allocate memory from the heap (not the stack). This is never automatically cleaned up and the programmer should call `delete a` at some point. After `a = someOtherPointer` you have no way to `delete` the memory that was allocated from the `heap` when you created the `new A()`. Evenif you call `delete a` after that you will only delete what is pointed to by the `someOtherPointer` and not the memory that was used when you called `new`.

This is something that you should revise using a C++ textbook.

Comment: Map is basically a pre-written header file supplied by the Stanford library. It should store pointers, I'm guessing, without any issues as that is what has been demonstrated in some of our starter code -- would it help to provide that?

Comment: would it also be possible to explain WHY these memory leaks are occurring? I'm not sure if I understand this concept correctly.

Comment: Also, when I try your version of the code, I get the error "cannot convert nodeT to nodeT*" in assignment...

Comment: This helped me to eventually figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Edited. I didn't see that you were assigning to dereferenced pointers. Glad it helped. What was the actual issue?

Comment: the reason that I was passing the data around using temporary objects was because I kept getting the cannot convert nodeT to nodeT*. Looking through your cleaned up code helped me to realize that the issue was really how I was passing the nodes in the map. The map should have been carrying pointers to nodes, rather than the structs themselves. Changing Map<nodeT> to Map<nodeT *> fixed it.

Comment: But it still should have had 2 pointers in it! Anyways glad it worked out for you.

Comment: BTW the memory leaks were cause because you are creating new objects on the **heap** and not maintaining any way to delete them. See edit in question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just to clarify, does allocation only happen when you use the word "new"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55983/discussion-between-dennis-and-marchon).